# How do you install Ubuntu on a partitioned drive (B:)?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

I wanted to install Ubuntu in my Windows 7 machine in a partitioned drive named 'B:', but if /dev/sda is my primary, what is my partitioned drive then?

Comment: You will want manual partitioning , see this guide: http://askubuntu.com/q/343268/295286  When you install, select "Something Else" option and you should see two partitions there - your windows one and the blank one. I'd suggest you remember its size to properly identify the partition

Answer (score 1):

The drive-letters assigned by Windows to drives or partitions are a Windows-internal thing. These drive-letters are not recognized by Ubuntu. Ubuntu uses a different system.

```
sda  is the first hard-disk-drive in your system
sdb  is the second hard-disk-drive in your system
sdc  is the third hard-disk-drive in your system
```

A hard-disk-drive may be divided in several partitions.for example, the first drive (sda is divided in three partitions)

```
sda1  is the first partition on the drive
sda2  is the second partition on the drive
sda3  is the third partition on the drive
```

I hope this gives you an overview how things work in Ubuntu.

In Windows, you can assign a label (name) to a partition. Partition-labels will be recognized by Ubuntu, using partition-labels would help you to find the  partition where you want to install Ubuntu. You may use any third-party partition-manager or the built in partition-tool from Windows to assign labels to the partitions.

If no labels are assigned to partitions, you will have to check the partition-size and/or the used file-system to find the correct partition.

Comment: Is sda1 is the main part which contained the windows?

Comment: now, let's say I have a hard drive with 3 parts in it, SYSTEM, C:, Ubuntu B: (i preserved this for the installation) and HP_TOOLS. What command line I should enter? *note, all of this are in a single drive.

Comment: Sorry, 4 parts.

Comment: There is nothing to enter in a command-line, just start the installer, choose `Something else` and go on. It seems you have labeled your partition, so it will be easy to find. You will not see drive letters `C: or B:` as this is a Windows-thing, but you can identify the correct partition by  label or size. See instructions in the link given by Serg in his comment...

Comment: they say that the arrangements of the commands is based in size. here is from small to big: HP_TOOLS, SYSTEM, B:, C:. so what is th command for B:?

Comment: not the command, the name as in /dev/sda

Comment: You know the size off your partition `B:` and you have labeled it `Ubuntu`. Start the installer and choose `Something else`. This will bring you to a screen where you can choose the partition to install. All partitions are listed there and that is the moment you will know the partition-number. Just look at it. Check the partition-size in Windows first to be sure. If it is sda1 or sda2 or sda3 or sda4 does not depend on the size of partitions. I can't tell you the correct number, I am not in front off your screen. You don't need to enter the number, just select the partition with mouse-click.